# VS2012, C++11 and memory leak detection (VLD vs CRTDBG)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

I had a bunch of memory leaks detected with CRTDBG but found them difficult to trace so installed Visual Leak Detection. This showed a consistent number of leaks which I traced to abstract classes not having virtual destructors. I fixed this and VLD now shows no memory leaks in my application, however CRTDBG still does and it's showing consistently around 100 or so leaks.

Can either of these tools be trusted with C++11? I'm heavily using unique pointers and barely making any new objects without them so can't understand where the leaks are coming from.

Comment: Do you have any global objects, perhaps with `unique_ptr`? If you do, these can be considered as "leaked memory."

Comment: You're right, I create an instance of my game engine in the main function which I don't delete before calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(). Silly me! It's on the stack so putting that instance inside a block before _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() reduces the leaks down to 1 with CRTDBG. Thanks! Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I just posted an answer. Anyway, upvoted your question! It is good to see that you care about memory leaks this much, I often wish other developers did the same...

Comment: Thanks, annoys me too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have some global objects or something on the stack in `main()`, they won't be destroyed before the `main()` exits.

If these objects do dynamic memory allocation and you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` at the very end of the `main()`, you will still see that memory as "leaked."